# Trying to create a list of squares of even numbers in a matrix, getting error

Tags: python, string-formatting

Newbie coder here, trying to complete a homework assignment:

Given below is a 2D matrix, create a list of squares of all the even numbers present in the matrix.

Here is my code:

```
myMatrix = [[1, 2, 'aa',3, 4],

        ['dd',5, 6, 7],

        [8, 9, 10,'cc']]
list=[i for row in myMatrix for i in row ]
V=[x**2 for x in list if x % 2 ==0]
V
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-6fae11330bf9> in <module>()
  5             [8, 9, 10,'cc']]
  6 list=[i for row in myMatrix for i in row ]
----> 7 V=[x**2 for x in list if x % 2 ==0]
  8 V

<ipython-input-95-6fae11330bf9> in <listcomp>(.0)
  5             [8, 9, 10,'cc']]
  6 list=[i for row in myMatrix for i in row ]
----> 7 V=[x**2 for x in list if x % 2 ==0]
  8 V

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_list = []
for row in myMatrix:
    for x in row:
        if isinstance(x, int) and x % 2 == 0:
            new_list.append(x ** 2)

print new_list
# [4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

Or via list comprehension:

```
new_list = [x**2 for row in myMatrix for x in row if instance(x, int) and x%2==0]
```

Also you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it's a reserved data type.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you tell me *why* my original code was failing?

Comment: Np. You forgot the `instance(x, int)` which filters out all of the non-integers items. You could also use `type(x)==int` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your matrix also contain `str` values along with `int`. And you can not perform the mod `%` operation on `str` object. If you will do, you will get [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.TypeError). For example:

```
>>> 'aa' % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Since your matrix is supposed to be a square of *even* numbers, why are you even using the `str` as a part of it?